# Shopify filter by multiple tags Inclusive 'OR' instead of 'AND'

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to get  products inclusive of any number of tags,
The tags on the URL work as 'AND' logic, Whereas I need 'OR' logic.
Eg: We are in the Hilux collection, and now we need to filter both headlights and wipers, The Shopify logic now wants to search for one product with both tags which doesn't exist.

Comment: What you have code so far? I would like to see your code and your expected output.

Comment: So far, I haven't needed to code for it. in the URL if you add tags  eg: "website.com/collection-name/tag1+tag2+tag3" the products containing all three tags (AND filters), Shopify has this feature builtin.
But I want OR type of filters  which i am not sure if shopify has by default.